# How to make iron-router's waitOn to show an animation instead of a whole template while waiting?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using the `waitOn` method in my router:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: "layout",
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});

this.route("bookPage", {
  path: "/books/:_id",
  waitOn: function() {
    return [Meteor.subscribe("singleBook", this.params._id), Meteor.subscribe("chapters", this.params._id)];
  },
  data: function() {
    return Books.findOne(this.params._id);
  }
});
```

Right now, a new template is loaded each time I click on a link. Is there a way to just show an animation before the next page loads?

Comment: What kind of animation? You can simply put an image of a spinning arrow in the loading template, but it's not that kind of animation you're talking about?

Comment: @Peppe L-G I want the animation to load in the *current* template, not a loading template.